# Unity CS1061 Error: Renderer does not contain definition for material

Tags: unity-game-engine

Used to work fine and after restarting my unity project this was a thing. I am buffled and not sure what could have caused this error, the definition of Renderer contains a material in the Unity doc.
[image]

I looked for the error, but it says that CS1061 means missing definition, but that is in contrast to the unity doc and em knowing the code used to not give that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GetComponent<MeshRenderer>()` instead.

Comment: I am just stumped as to why it worked before. Introducing a different type of renderer maybe confuses the compiler, so now he wants a more concrete type definition. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey forgot to add if it's a character model mesh you should use `GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>()`